# Is fancybox self binding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, fancybox-2

I have written a gallery plugin which uses fancybox for the popup.  This all works but I have an issue where I do an ajax call and replace all the images depending on some filters.

```
$.ajax({
    url: this.action,
    type: this.method,
    data: $(this).serialize() + '&filter=submit&isAjax=true',
    success: function (result) {
        photoHolder.html(result);
    }
});
```

Now I would expect that I should have to rebind the fancybox to the new content so in my success I thought I would have had to do something like:

```
photoHolder.html(result);
photoHolder.find('.fancybox').fancybox();
```

However I have not, but the fancybox is working on the new content.  Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: What version are you using? Latest?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Version 2.1.5

Comment: Are you using get method in your ajax call? And have you got any error on firebug console?

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL no, the method is a post and the console shows no errors - just `XHR finished loading: "http://test.local/photo-gallery". `

Comment: and `fancybox` class is belong to a link? Also be sure that your ajax call can call the url in network tab of firebug

Comment: yes the link looks like this: `<a href="/Venus-Cycle-Shelter-7993.jpg?MaxWidth=1920&amp;MaxHeight=1080" class="fancybox" title="Venus Cycle Shelter"><img src="/Venus-Cycle-Shelter-7993.jpg?MaxWidth=200&amp;MaxHeight=200" alt="Thumbnail of Venus Cycle Shelter"></a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does work for run-time added elements.

See the "live" parameter in the [docs](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/).
`true` is the default.

Comment: ah, never knew what that option was for!  Very interesting

Comment: The name of the parameter comes from jQuery's first attempt at dynamic event handling. It's deprecated now in favor of `on`, but the docs still cover it: https://api.jquery.com/live/